# Form submit and redirection in zend form

Tags: javascript, zend-form, form-submit

I have a zend form if i click submit button i should get message box and click ok i should submit the form and redirect to some other page..

Here is my zend form code

```
$aElements[] = new Rst_Form_Element_Submit(new Zend_Config_Ini($ini_path, 'submit'));

$this->getElement('submit')->setAttrib(
    'onclick',
    'if (confirm("are u sure?")) { document.form.submit(); document.location.href = "/role"; } return false;'
    );
```

please help me out.
kiran

Answer (score 0):

`document` do not have its `form` attribute.
Can you try like this?
`document.forms[0].submit()`

edit:
Or you can submit with form id
`document.getElementById('formid').submit()`

Comment: Hi vusan, document.form.submit() is working the next one redirection is not working here.

Comment: { document.form.submit(); document.location.href = "/role"; } is this format is correct?

Comment: Your script will not work because `document.form.submit();` will return undefined error. Hope [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) will help you on fixing your error.

Comment: yes in console i am getting document.form.submit(); undefined error..so what should i do?

Comment: No same prob i am getting but data is saving in the database.but not redirecting to /role

Comment: You have to redirect with server side language not with javascript.